# Showing Bitmaps one after another in wxpython at a certain point overlaps them and doesn't show the rest

Tags: python-3.x, bitmap, wxpython, bitmapimage

I'm building a simple program in Python to show some images stored in some folders. The program goes from folder to folder showing one image after another like this:

```
for x in range(len(gl)):
    for y in range(tn[x]):
        png = wx.Image("{}\\{}\\{}".format(username, gl[x], pnglist[tot + y]), wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        delpng.append(wx.StaticBitmap(self.scrollWin, -1, png, (0, 56 * (tot + y)), (56, 56)))
    tot += tn[x]
```

At a certain point, the images stop showing correctly, overlapping, and then don't appear at all.

[Correctly showing images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsXws.png)

[Overlapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SssrK.png)

All the images have 56 pixels of width and height. I've got no idea of what can be causing this.

For the folders it goes through:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/l5t2uk9d2d1o7o0/GamerM3243.rar/file

And as for the code:

```
import wx

#username = str(input("Username: "))
username = "GamerM3243"
delpng = []

def ShowImages(self, username):
    gl = []
    glif = [0]
    pnglist = []
    rpnglist = []
    tn = []

    fl = open("{}\\{}'s Trophies.txt".format(username, username), "r", encoding = "utf-8-sig").read().split('\n')
    self.scrollWin = wx.ScrolledWindow(self, -1, size = (700, 500))

    for i, n in enumerate(fl):
        if ''.join(list(n)[:25]) == "Number of trophies earned":
            gl.append(fl[i-1])
            tn.append(int(''.join(list(n)[27:])))

    glif = [i for i, n in enumerate(fl) if n in gl]

    for i, n in enumerate(gl):
        gl[i] = ''.join([x for x in list(n) if x != ":" and x != "?" and x != '"'])

    for i, n in enumerate(glif):
        i1 = n + 2
        try: 
            i2 = glif[i + 1] - 1      
        except IndexError:
            i2 = -1
        rpnglist.append(fl[i1:i2])

    for x in rpnglist:
        for y in x:
            if y != "" and y not in gl:
                pnglist.append(y)

    for i, n in enumerate(pnglist):
        for x, z in enumerate(list(n)):
            if z == "-" and n[x - 1] == " " and n[x + 1] == " ":
                pnglist[i] = ''.join(list(n)[:x - 1])

    for i, n in enumerate(pnglist):
        pnglist[i] = "{}.png".format(''.join([x for x in list(n) if x != ":" and x != "?" and x != '"']))

    tot = 0

    for x in range(len(gl)):
        for y in range(tn[x]):
                png = wx.Image("{}\\{}\\{}".format(username, gl[x], pnglist[tot + y]), wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
                delpng.append(wx.StaticBitmap(self.scrollWin, -1, png, (0, 56 * (tot + y)), (56, 56)))
        tot += tn[x]

    self.scrollWin.SetScrollbars(0, 1, 1400, 56 * tot)
    self.Layout()
    self.Show(True) 

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title = title, size = (700, 500))
        ShowImages(self, username)

app = wx.App(False)
frame = MainWindow(None, "{}'s Trophies".format(username))
app.MainLoop()
```

You just need to unzip the file and then place the .py file outside folder.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: please post a minimum working example and steps to re-create the issue

Answer (score 0):

***------------ Edit -------------***

I ran the code and printed the object positions and it looks like its hitting some internal limit within wxpython. The images reach a certain y coordinate and then just stack up on top of each other.

I tried using a scrolled canvas as well as adding the bitmaps to a sizer and they all produced roughly the same result.

You might have to re-think your design. There might be too many items to display without running out of computer resources. I would recommend paginating the images to prevent loading too many images at once or try adding them to a listctrl in LC_ICON mode.

I updated the code to display to fill the window with the images instead of just a single column. It seems to display them all:

```
import wx

# username = str(input("Username: "))
username = "GamerM3243"
delpng = []


class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(700, 500))
        self.ShowImages(username)

    def ShowImages(self, username):
        gl = []
        glif = [0]
        pnglist = []
        rpnglist = []
        tn = []

        fl = open("{}\\{}'s Trophies.txt".format(username, username), "r", encoding="utf-8-sig").read().split('\n')
        self.scrollWin = wx.ScrolledWindow(self, -1, size=(700, 500))

        for i, n in enumerate(fl):
            if ''.join(list(n)[:25]) == "Number of trophies earned":
                gl.append(fl[i - 1])
                tn.append(int(''.join(list(n)[27:])))

        glif = [i for i, n in enumerate(fl) if n in gl]

        for i, n in enumerate(gl):
            gl[i] = ''.join([x for x in list(n) if x != ":" and x != "?" and x != '"'])

        for i, n in enumerate(glif):
            i1 = n + 2
            try:
                i2 = glif[i + 1] - 1
            except IndexError:
                i2 = -1
            rpnglist.append(fl[i1:i2])

        for x in rpnglist:
            for y in x:
                if y != "" and y not in gl:
                    pnglist.append(y)

        for i, n in enumerate(pnglist):
            for x, z in enumerate(list(n)):
                if z == "-" and n[x - 1] == " " and n[x + 1] == " ":
                    pnglist[i] = ''.join(list(n)[:x - 1])

        for i, n in enumerate(pnglist):
            pnglist[i] = "{}.png".format(''.join([x for x in list(n) if x != ":" and x != "?" and x != '"']))

        tot = 0

        col_count = self.GetSize()[0] // 56
        # col_wid = col_count * 56

        for x in range(len(gl)):
            for y in range(tn[x]):
                png = wx.Image("{}\\{}\\{}".format(username, gl[x], pnglist[tot + y]),
                               wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
                # print(56 * (tot + y))

                row, col = divmod(tot + y, col_count)
                pos = (56 * col, 56 * row)
                bmp = wx.StaticBitmap(self.scrollWin, -1, png, pos, (56, 56))

                delpng.append(bmp)

            tot += tn[x]
        self.scrollWin.SetScrollbars(0, 1, 1400, 56 * tot / col_count)
        self.Show()


app = wx.App(False)
frame = MainWindow(None, "{}'s Trophies".format(username))
app.MainLoop()
```

***----------- Edit #2 -------------***

The follow-up question is probably better suited for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but here is a quick re-write using only 1 loop:

```
import wx, os

# username = str(input("Username: "))
username = "GamerM3243"
delpng = []
this_dir = os.path.abspath(".")
img_size = (56, 56)


def remove_illegal_chars(text):
    """
    :param text:
    :type text:
    :return: removes characters from a string that aren't allowed in windows filenames
    :rtype:
    """
    illegal = '":?/\<>|*'
    return "".join(c for c in text if c not in illegal)


def extract_fname(line_text):
    """
    :param line_text: a line of text from trophies.txt
    :type line_text:
    :return: the corresponding file name
    :rtype:
    """
    return remove_illegal_chars(line_text).split(" - Earned on")[0] + ".png"


def get_image_path(username, game_folder, line_text):
    """
    :param username:
    :type username:
    :param game_folder:
    :type game_folder:
    :param line_text:
    :type line_text:
    :return:
    :rtype:
    """
    return os.path.join(this_dir, username, game_folder, extract_fname(line_text))


class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(700, 500))
        self.scrollWin = None
        self.show_images(username)

    def show_images(self, username):
        self.scrollWin = wx.ScrolledWindow(self, -1, size=(700, 500))

        trophy_path = os.path.join(username, f"{username}'s Trophies.txt")
        with open(trophy_path, "r", encoding="utf-8-sig") as fileobj:
            lines = fileobj.read().split("\n")

        col_count = self.GetSize()[0] // img_size[0]
        last_line = None
        game_folder = None
        total_imgs = 0
        for line in lines:
            if line.startswith("Number of trophies earned"):
                # trophy count line, preceded by game title line
                game_folder = last_line
            elif "Earned on" in line:
                # trophy line
                img_path = get_image_path(username, game_folder, line)
                self.create_image(img_path, total_imgs, col_count)
                total_imgs += 1
            else:
                # possible game title
                last_line = remove_illegal_chars(line)
        self.scrollWin.SetScrollbars(0, 1, 1400, img_size[0] * total_imgs / col_count)
        self.Show()

    def create_image(self, img_path, img_number, col_count):
        bmp = wx.Bitmap(img_path)
        row, col = divmod(img_number, col_count)
        pos = (img_size[0] * col, img_size[0] * row)
        wx.StaticBitmap(self.scrollWin, -1, bmp, pos)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        app = wx.App(False)
        frame = MainWindow(None, "{}'s Trophies".format(username))
        app.MainLoop()
    except:
        import traceback

        traceback.print_exc()
        input()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll take into account from now on. But that doesn't seem to work for me. What should I put in your commented section? I tried putting nothing, and even a time.sleep() but nothing worked.

Comment: Thanks! My intention was to display the images in a single column and have text next to each of them, but if nothing else works I will go with more than one column. I'll also try to to paginate it or add them to a listctrl. By the way, do you have any ideas in how to shorten all the for loops? Not that it doesn't work properly, but I would like it to be more compact. Thanks again!